# “ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous”

Tags: python, numpy, voronoi

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to do some Voronoi analysis so I need to store each polygon area and its neighbors as well. I look for each polygon vertices if it is in the others polygons so I can define them as neighbor and calculate its area or just pass to the next. I execute the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


inst=np.zeros((360,2))
inst1=-0.5+np.random.random((300,2))
inst1[:,:2]*=3.9
inst1[:,:2]+=4
inst2=4+0.5*np.random.random((30,2))
inst3=5+0.2*np.random.random((30,2))

for i in range(len(inst1)):
    inst[i]=inst1[i]
for i in range(len(inst2)):
    inst[len(inst1)+i]=inst2[i]
    inst[len(inst1)+len(inst2)+i]=inst3[i]

vor=Voronoi(inst[:,:2])
reg=vor.regions

poly_v0=[]    
poly_vf=[]
for region in reg:
    if not -1 in region:
        poly_v0=[vor.vertices[i] for i in region]
        poly_vf.append(poly_v0)


vor_surf=[[]]
punto=[]    
for i in range(len(poly_vf)):      
    a=np.zeros((len(poly_vf[i]),2))
    for j in range(len(a[:,0])):
        a[j]=poly_vf[i][j]
    vor_surf.append(0.5*np.abs(np.dot(a[:,0],np.roll(a[:,1],1))-np.dot(a[:,1],
                               np.roll(a[:,0],1))))
    for vertices in poly_vf:
        for punto in vertices:

            for n in range(len(poly_vf)-1):
                z=punto in poly_vf[n]
                if punto in poly_vf[n].any():
                    b=np.zeros((len(poly_vf[n]),2))
                    for k in range(len(b[:,0])):
                        b[k]=poly_vf[n][k]
                    vor_surf[i].append(0.5*np.abs(np.dot(b[:,0],np.roll(b[:,1],1))-np.dot(b[:,1],np.roll(b[:,0],1))))


voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=False)
plt.plot(inst[:,0], inst[:,1], 'o', ms=3)
plt.show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Voronoi-voisin.py", line 45, in <module>
    z=punto in poly_vf[n+1]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you print `type(punto)` and `type(poly_vf[n+1])`?

Comment: Probably you are trying to do `[array] in [scalar]`.

Comment: punto is float64 with size (2,) and it is a single vertex and poly_vf[n+1] is a list composed by all the vertex (float64 (2,)) of a single polygon.

Comment: for    type(punto) it says    'numpy.ndarray' and for    type(poly_vf[n+1]) it says    'list'